# How to search a set of input strings in an excel file and return all the matched rows using Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am taking a set of strings as an input, for example, 'rollback batch', and searching in an excel file which is having structure as below

[image]

I want to return all the rows which got matched with any of the sub-string from the input but in the output I am getting all the rows

Here what I have tried :

```
import xlrd

def open_file(path, search_string):
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(path)
    sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)


    for row_num in range(sheet.nrows):
        row_value = sheet.row_values(row_num)
        if any(x in search_string for x in row_value[1]):
            print (row_value)


path = "DATAFIX_LIST.xlsx"
search_string = input('Enter Search String -->')
search_string_list = search_string.split()
open_file(path, search_string)
```

Output :-

[image]

The expected output is

['DF1', 'BATCH ROLLBACK']

['DF2', 'TIAFLEX BATCH ROLLBACK']

['DF3', 'TRANSACTION ROLLBACK']

Comment: I think you are very close check the following statement: any(x in search_string for x in row_value[1]) is x a string in this case? I think what you are comparing are the letter in the string so in the case of BATCH ROLLBACK x is B, A, T, C, H etc...

Comment: I think the fix would be to change any(x in search_string for x in row_value[1]) to if (row_value[1] in search_string):

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the program for it.

```
import xlrd

def open_file(path, search_string):
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(path)
    sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

    search_string_list = search_string.split()

    results = [] # holding row_num and keyword match frequency
    for row_num in range(sheet.nrows):

        row_value = sheet.row_values(row_num)

        keyword_match = 0 
        for keyword in search_string_list:
            if keyword.lower() in row_value[1].lower():
                # increasing keyword match frequency if it matches with a record
                keyword_match += 1

        # appending a list containing row_num and no of keywords matched to our
        # list if atleast one keyword is matched
        if keyword_match:
            results.append([row_num, keyword_match])    

    # sorting our results list in descending order of keyword match count
    results.sort(key = lambda results: results[1], reverse=True)

    # printing rows of our "DATAFIX_LIST.xlsx" file on basis of first index 
    # (row num) of all the rows stored
    for result in results:
        print(sheet.row_values(result[0]))

path = "DATAFIX_LIST.xlsx"
search_string = input('Enter Search String --> ')
open_file(path, search_string)
```

File Contents:

[image: Contents of "DATAFIX_LIST.xlsx" file]

Output:

```
Enter Search String --> rollback batch TEMP
['DF9', 'TEMP BATCH ROLLBACK']
['DF1', 'BATCH ROLLBACK']
['DF2', 'TIAFLEX BATCH ROLLBACK']
['DF10', 'STAMPS BATCH ROLLBACK']
['DF3', 'TRANSACTION ROLLBACK']
```

Here, we made a list of input string by splitting it and then checking if it exists in all the entries of DATAFIX_LIST.xlsx file one by one.

If any of the keyword matched with entry, we incremented the keyword_match variable by 1 and continued this process for all the keywords.

After checking all the keywords in a row, we appended a list containing row_num and number of keywords matched to results list. Then, we sorted results in descending order on the basis of number of keywords matched.

Also, we converted our strings to lowercase to avoid string case related problems.

EDIT: As per the request of @vasudha-dixit (user:6087065), most similar rows are now displayed first.

Comment: Also I was wondering how to print most matched row on the top?

Comment: I have added **most matched row** feature in my previous answer. Please, have a look in it.

Comment: My Pleasure. :)  @VasudhaDixit